# incomplete type GLFWwindow when wrapping a C++ class

Tags: c++, boost-python

I am trying to derive from an `Application` C++ base class in Python with Boost::Python and am struggling with wrapping the GLFW callbacks, particularly due to the `GLFWwindow* window` argument.

Here's the MCVE:

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <boost/python.hpp>

class Application
{
public:
    Application();
    GLFWwindow* window;
    virtual int onKeyPressed(GLFWwindow*, int, int, int , int);
};

Application *app;

Application::Application()
{
    glfwInit();
    window = glfwCreateWindow(800.0, 600.0, "example", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
}

int Application::onKeyPressed(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    return 1;
}

struct ApplicationWrap : Application, boost::python::wrapper<Application>
{
    int onKeyPressed(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
    {
        return this->get_override("onKeyPressed")(window, key, scancode, action, mods);
    }
};

static void _onKeyPressed(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    app->onKeyPressed(window, key, scancode, action, mods);
}


int main() {
    // app = new Application();
    // glfwSetKeyCallback(app->window, _onKeyPressed);
    // delete app;
    return 0;
}


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
    namespace python = boost::python;

    python::class_<ApplicationWrap, boost::noncopyable>("Application")
    //.def("onKeyPressed", _onKeyPressed).staticmethod("_onKeyPressed")
    ;
}

// import example
// class DerivedApplication(example.Application):
//     def __init__(self):
//         example.Application.__init__(self)
//     def onKeyPressed(window):
//         print("successfully overrides example.Application.onKeyPressed.")

// DerivedApplication()
```

compiling with:

```
g++ -I/usr/include/python3.7 main.cpp -lglfw -lpython3.7 -lboost_python3
```

> error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct GLFWwindow’
> typeid(T)
> ^~~~~~~~~
>
> note: forward declaration of ‘struct GLFWwindow’  typedef struct
> GLFWwindow GLFWwindow;

Thanks for any feedback on how this problem is to be solved.

Comment: What line of code does the error point to?

Comment: Hi, It occurs at `int onKeyPressed(...)` inside `ApplicationWrap`. I am trying to write a more thorough example because I just realized that `onKeyPressed` need to be static to be passed to `glfwSetKeyCallback`.

Comment: Try `BOOST_PYTHON_OPAQUE_SPECIALIZED_TYPE_ID(GLFWwindow)` to register it as an [opaque pointer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/python/doc/v2/opaque.html#opaque-spec-synopsis).

Comment: @dxiv That fixes it :) I will have to read up on how that works. You turn it into an answer if you want the rep. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it helped. And, yes, please look it up and doublecheck, since it's been some time since I last played with these, and there may be newer tricks I need to learn too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from `template <class T> inline type_info type_id()` via...

```
template <class T>
struct registered_pointee
    : registered<
        typename boost::python::detail::remove_pointer<  // <-- fails for incomplete types
           typename boost::python::detail::remove_cv<
              typename boost::python::detail::remove_reference<T>::type
           >::type
        >::type
    >
{
};
```

...and originally from `pointer_deep_arg_to_python<Ptr>::pointer_deep_arg_to_python(Ptr x)`.

To register `GLFWwindow *` as an [opaque pointer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/python/doc/v2/opaque.html), insert the following after the `#include`'s.

```
BOOST_PYTHON_OPAQUE_SPECIALIZED_TYPE_ID(GLFWwindow)
```